# Pack a jar to work as a blackbox (with resources)

Tags: java, maven, jar, include

I have a rather large project, which uses a lot of jars, all meant for normal usage and therefore use files as the following:

> new File(relativePath);

Now I need to use that project as part of a Jersey/Maven/Glassfish project, which surely enough has a much better way to load file, namely as an InputStream.

Now, some of the files in my original project are only compiled classes which means I can't change the way they load the files (I can change the file's path though).
I've packed the entire project using the 'pack for store' and gave it a try, but all I got was a FileNotFoundException.

Is there any way to pack the project along with all the resources to run as a black box, or as if it was running locally?
Any other ideas on how to do that would also be greatly appreciated.